Elsa vs Temportal vs Camunda vs Workflow Core
We're in the process of assessing workflow engines that are compatible with .NET 8, and I'd greatly value input from the community. I'm eager to hear about your experiences and implementation stories to help inform our decision.
Elsa: Elsa Workflow's visual workflow designer makes it very beginner-friendly and intuitive. Developers who prefer a more visual approach to workflow design often find Elsa Workflow easier to grasp and work with. The visual interface can streamline the process of creating and managing workflows, reducing the learning curve for developers.
Workflow Core: open source,  Workflow Core is also known for its simplicity and ease of use, but it's more code-centric compared to Elsa Workflow. While it doesn't offer a visual designer out of the box, it provides clean and intuitive APIs for defining workflows programmatically. Developers comfortable with coding will find Workflow Core straightforward to integrate and use within their .NET applications.
Temporal: Temporal provides robust support for BPM workflows with features such as workflow orchestration, task scheduling, state management, and long-running process execution. It's designed to handle complex business processes at scale while ensuring reliability, fault tolerance, and durability. open source and active support available but only concern is first language not .net. There can be limitation when we developing using .net.
Camunda: Camunda is specifically designed for BPM and workflow automation. It offers a comprehensive suite of BPM features, including process modeling, execution, monitoring, and optimization. open source and active support available but only concern is first language not .net. There can be limitation when we developing using .net.
After conducting research, I'm leaning towards Elsa workflow for our microservices-based application (which requires minimal code expertise). However, expert insights are crucial. Have you witnessed successful deployments of workflow solutions with .NET applications? If yes, which one would you recommend?

Your question is an interesting summary of some of the available options for the job, but don't you think it really depends on your requirements which you haven't provided much on?

I selected above base on my requirement @VahidNaderi Thanks.

So I hope you opt for Elsa, I like it and it feels the right size with a promising future.

One thing to mention is that coding approach in ELSA is doable in 2 ways either using an standard object oriented way to create a workflow directly but on WorkflowCore it is hars todo something similar as because of its fluent API and the fact that there is a lot of templating you might find out that if you want to create a workflow in runtime by reading data from some other system you will probably give up.
Here Elsa has a dual approach having a fluent API (a builder) for simplicity in case you workflow is hard coded but also providing an easy way directly using its objects to build up the workflow at runtime.
Elsa supports custom actions/trigger but no option to derive from workflow class, so that is a small disadvantage but you are able to work around this.
